# How to get emulator to stop demanding certificates

Tags: certificate, emulation

I've managed to get the emulator in the WTK to run stand-alone, as a QwertyDevice, and to install apps (with the built-in Install Applications app) from the Apache server on my laptop. However, it's refusing to actually *run* the apps because it can't find a Certificate (or the Certificate is corrupted).

How do I turn that off? My actual *phone*, which I'm developing my apps for, warns me but lets me install and use unsigned apps. And I think I can trust my own apps since *I'm writing them*.

I found mention of a security Xdomain setting in the WTK user guide, and tried the default, trusted, untrusted, and minimum. No effect except a message in the Command Prompt window saying that it's running in the selected domain. It still refuses to run my apps. (Selecting -Xdomain:help in an attempt to get a list of valid domains resulted in "Running in the help domain"!)

How do I get the emulator to OBEY ME and run the apps?

Comment: I will add that if I let BlueJ's deploy function start the emulator, I don't get this problem. I get repeatedly asked for permission to access the filesystem; but the App does do what it's supposed to. So it's something BlueJ is doing that I'm not doing when I run standalone. But what?? BlueJ when run from a Command Prompt goes to background and shows nothing in the terminal window.